# Modifying key string in array object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array of object :

```
[{url:"http://www.url1",value: "number1"},{url:"http://www.url2",value: "number2"},{url: "http://www.url3", value: "number3"},etc...]
```

I would like to replace all the `http://www.` with an empty string.

looking at some answers, I've found this :

```
var resultArr = arr.map(function(x){return x.replace(/http://www./g, '');});
```

However it doesn't apply in my case since `map` is only working for array.

so I've also look at this :

```
array = [{url:1,value: 2},{url:3,value: 4},{url: 5, value: 6}]

Object.keys(array).map(function(url, value) {
   array[value] *= 2;
});
```

but return me this : `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`. Moreover for this last solution I don't really know where I should use `.replace(/,/g, '')` method...

any idea ?

Comment: Be aware that you need to escape the special characters in your regex. You could however do `.split('.').pop()` to get `url1`, `url2` and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

es5:

```
array.map(function(element) {
  return {
    value: element.value,
    url: element.url.replace('http://www.', '')
  }
})
```

es6+:

```
array.map(element => ({
   ...element,
   url: element.url.replace('http://www.', '')
}))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the syntax right. `map` is OK, or in this case `forEach` as you mutate:

```js
var array = [{url:'http://www.example.com?xyz',value: 2},
             {url:'http://www.example.com?ok',value: 4},
             {url:'http://www.example.com?hello', value: 6}]

array.forEach(function(obj) {
   obj.value *= 2;
   obj.url = obj.url.replace(/http:\/\/www\./g, '');
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate over the array like this:

```
array.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.url = entry.url.replace('http://www.','');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! `map` is not really the way to go, since you want to modify the items of the list. `forEach` makes more sense

```js
var lst = [{
  url: "http://www.url1",
  value: "number1"
}, {
  url: "http://www.url2",
  value: "number2"
}, {
  url: "http://www.url3",
  value: "number3"
}];

lst.forEach(obj => 
            Object.keys(obj)
                 .forEach(key => 
                          obj[key] = obj[key].replace(/http:\/\/www\./g, '')));

console.log(lst);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [{url:"http://www.url1",value: "number1"},{url:"http://www.url2",value: "number2"},{url: "http://www.url3", value: "number3"}];
for (var i=0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
    array[i].url = array[i].url.replace("http://www.", "");
};
console.log(array);
```